# Instance variable with static functions in java

Tags: java

If an instance variable is declared inside a static function or static block, will the memory space be created for the instance variable again or not?

What about main function? 
In java main function is static 
Can I declare an instance variable in main.. and if I can, will memory space be allocated for it at the time of compilation or only during object creation?

Comment: Care to give a sample of code ?

Comment: You can't declare instance variables inside methods, only local variables (unless you're talking about a local class, of course).

Answer (score 1):

> If an instance variable is declared inside a static function or static
>   block,

Lest stop here - you cannot declare instance variable in static block as there is no instance context thus:

```
static{
    this.whatrever=x;
}
```

is invalid and wont even compile.

The same situation is with `public static main` - this is static context thus `this.x` expression will not compile.

You can reffer to static variables/methods from instance context but not the other way around.